# Make one data frame column in R unchanged to filters

Tags: r

I have data frame in R. It have some columns with: dates, numbers, texts and 1 column which made by row_number().
I need to make column with row_number - unchanged. So, when in a view mode I make some column filters with others column, not with row_number column, this column (row_number) must be always show the same numbers (1, 2, 3...).
For example:

```
**row_number | id | name | date_create**
1            3   Devid   2019-06-15
2            2   Paul    2019-02-19
3            6   Andrew  2020-04-24
4            5   Jhon    2019-12-02
```

And when I use filter (in a view mode) on id, it's must be:

```
**row_number | id | name | date_create**
1            2   Paul    2019-02-19
2            3   Devid   2019-06-15
3            5   Jhon    2019-12-02
4            6   Andrew  2020-04-24
```

Comment: I'd suggest always adding that column at the end of your code. So, for instance, you do all your transformations and, at the end, provide a *dplyr* pipe. 

`data <- data %>% arrange(name) %>% mutate(row_number = c(1:length(data))`


This way, *row_number* would always return the row index for each transformation that you'd make. It's boring and not very effective, but i couldn't think of another way to perform what you asked.

Comment: Thx for your solution proposal, Gabriel Reis.
But unfortunately, it will be reload all table. And in my case when I use the filter it must make only rearrange rows without reload =\

Comment: Exactly! I can't visualize a solution that doesn't require this constant reload, I'm afraid. This is because *row_number* will always be attached with a specific row, and then when you rearrange, he'll follow that row. I hope you can find a good solution!